# Thymeleaf + Spring mvc Variable

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing an app using Spring Boot where, if there is an error, i have 3 possible case (let's assume error1, error2 and error3).

When an error is taken, i must redirect the user to an error page that must show a different message error based on the error verified.

For example, if the error 1 is taken, in the error page the user must see "Sorry, error 1 verified. Pelease control" but, if the error is the second, the error page must show "Ehi, wake up!".

Now, the question is: how i can perform this task using Thymeleaf as engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put an error code in your model, e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something")
public ModelAndView process(...) {

    String errorCode = ...;

    ModelAndView ret = new ModelAndView();

    ret.setViewName("someview");
    ret.addObject("errorCode", errorCode);

    return ret;
}
```

Then use [conditional logic](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation) to show different [messages](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages). E.g.:

```
<div th:switch="${errorCode}">
  <p th:case="'error1'" th:text="#{error1}">Error 1!</p>
  <p th:case="'error2'" th:text="#{error2}">Error 2!</p>
  <p th:case="'error3'" th:text="#{error3}">Error 3!</p>
  <p th:case="*">Unknown error!</p>
</div>
```